# Запрос update на большой таблице

Tags: python, sql, oracle, update, database-cursor

Имеется таблица с 2,5 млн строками. Необходимо изменить ее скриптом. Вычитал, что метод `fetchall()` не рекомендуется использовать, т.к. результат запроса будет помещен в память. Использую `fetchmany()`:

```
def GetData(cur):
v_query = """select fio_contact, id_contact from atb_segmen_email_col where fio_contact is not null"""
u_query = """update atb_segmen_email_col set sex = :v1 where id_contact = :v2"""
cur.execute(v_query)
sql = cur.fetchmany(100)
while sql:
    for row in sql:
        v_id = row[0]
        w = morph.parse(translit(str(row[0]), 'ru'))[0].tag.gender
        cur.execute(u_query, {'v1' : w, 'v2: v_id'})
        cur.execute('commit')
    sql = cur.fetchmany(100)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> cx_oracle.InterfaceError: not a query

Что не так? Может есть другой способ, более быстрый?

Даже до возникновения ошибки, запрос на изменение был совсем медленный.

Comment: Поправил, как есть

Comment: Я бы попробовал "апдейтить" кусками (скажем по 1000) используя [executemany()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14905823/5741205)

Comment: MaxU, а по-поводу ошибки, не знаете? Я предполагаю что след. 100 строк он взять не может?

Comment: А на какую строку ругается? На `cur.execute('commit')`?

Comment: на sql = cur.fetchmany(100)

Comment: После выполнения `for` в `cur` будет содержаться результат коммита а не селекта.

Comment: Arnial, а как тогда? как писали выше через executemany()? с комитом после пачки

Comment: второй `sql = cur.fetchmany(100)` вообще не нужен. А вообще советую воспользоваться подходом из ссылки, которую я указал раньше

Comment: Можно апдейтнуть всю таблицу одним запросом. Разве так не будет быстрее чем запускать большое количество запросов меняющих по одной записи?

Answer (score 3):

> Может есть другой способ, более быстрый?

Выполнять массовые (*bulk*) изменения. Для этого, аналогично `fetchmany()`, есть [executemany()](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany). Например, сделать так:

```
conn = connect (<params>)
curq = conn.cursor ()
curu = conn.cursor ()
qry = '''
    select rowid, fio  
    from contact 
    where sex = 'x' and fio is not null 
    '''
curu.prepare ('update contact set sex=:1 where rowid=:2') 
curq.execute (qry)
numrows = 10000
while True:
    sources = curq.fetchmany (numrows)
    if not sources: 
        break
    # для теста вместо morph.parse() анализ по первой букве
    targets = [('f',rid) if (val[0] == 'Ж') else ('m',rid) for (rid, val) in sources]
    curu.executemany (None, targets)
    conn.commit ()
conn.close ()
```

Заметьте, использовать надо `ROWID` вместо `id`.
Результат на следуюшей тестовой таблице:

```
create table contact (id, fio, sex) as
    select rownum, case mod (rownum, 3) when 0 then 'Жен.' else 'Муж.' end||' имя', 'x'
    from dual connect by level <= 10e5
/
select fio, sex, count (sex) num from contact 
group by fio, sex
/
-- до 
FIO            S        NUM
-------------- - ----------
Муж. имя       x     666667
Жен. имя       x     333333

-- после
FIO            S        NUM
-------------- - ----------
Муж. имя       m     666667
Жен. имя       f     333333
```

---

PS Ошибки в коде вопроса:

- `cur.execute('commit')` надо заменить на `connection.commit()`
- `v_id = row[0]` получено из `fio_contact`, надо `v_id = row[1]`

Answer (score 2):

Другой подход. Более оптимальное решение -- отказаться от обновления таблицы пакетами, а обновить её одним единственным запросом. Это даст несомненный прирост производительности

Препятствием на пути к этому является лексический анализ с `morph.parse(...)`, что по сути есть подготовка данных (тоже может быть времязатратной). В большинстве похожих сценариев, имеет смысл поделить задачу на следующие шаги:

1. подготовка данных
2. массовое обновление на основе подготовленных данных

Для тестовых данных из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171988), понадобится дополнительно временная таблица:

```sql
create global temporary table gttnewvalues (rid rowid, sex char (1))
/
```

Рабочий пример реализации кода скрипта:

```py
conn = connect (<connect params>)
curqry = conn.cursor ()
curdml = conn.cursor ()

qry = '''
    select rowid, fio  
    from contact 
    where sex = 'x' and fio is not null 
    '''
curqry.execute (qry)
numrows = 10000
while True:
    sources = curqry.fetchmany (numrows)
    if not sources: 
        break
    # для теста вместо morph.parse() анализ по первой букве
    targets = [(rid, 'f') if (val[0] == 'Ж') else (rid,'m') for (rid, val) in sources]
    curdml.executemany ('insert into gttnewvalues values (:1, :2)', targets)

curdml.execute ('''
    merge into contact t
    using (
        select rid, sex newval  
        from gttnewvalues n) s
    on (t.rowid = s.rid) 
    when matched then update set sex = newval
''') 
conn.commit ()
conn.close ()
```